# default mat radio button check

Tags: angular, typescript

I tried now a few ways to set a mat radio button checked by default but none of these were working. Currently, my solution looks like that, which is also not working:

```html
<mat-radio-group name="personTypOperator" [(ngModel)]="personTypOperator" (change)="sendToFilter()" >
  <mat-radio-button checked value="and"  > Und </mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button value="or" > Oder </mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button value="not"> Nicht </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

I tried it this way through the "checked" element. I also tried [checked] before and it was also a failure. What is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select the 1st radio button option by default, you can initialize the `personTypOperator` property value in your Component `ts` file as:

```ts
personTypOperator = 'and';

// in case if assignment done within any function
this.personTypOperator = 'and';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can not solve your problem by updating the **angular** and **material** or by removing **npm** and reinstalling it, you can also try this method: use the

```html
<mat-checkbox>
```

instead of the

```html
<mat-radio-button>
```

And use

```html
<mat-form-field>
```

or

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef = "checked">
```

or

```html
<div>
```

or ... as the parent tag.

Comment: A mat-radio-button is not the same as a mat-checkbox

Comment: No, but you can have a similar use

Answer (score 0):

```html
<mat-radio-group name="personTypOperator" [(ngModel)]="personTypOperator" (change)="sendToFilter()" >
  <mat-radio-button checked value="and" checked="true" > Und </mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button value="or" > Oder </mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button value="not"> Nicht </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```